# Localhost website on a specific port

Tags: localhost, port

I set up php and mysql on my macbook, and I get the info page when I go to localhost, so I'm ready to start working on my website, but I want to develop on a specific port. So how can I make my server listen on say localhost:2727? Is there a configuration file I need to edit?

Im using the stock OS X webserver, so I believe its apache.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Whatever is stock on mac os x. So I believe Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been adding my vhosts configurations to the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file located for me at `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. Try adding something like the following to that file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:2727
<VirtualHost *:2727>
     ServerAdmin you@email.com
     DocumentRoot "/Users/you/Sites/"
     ServerName dev.site.com
     ErrorLog "/Users/you/log/apache2/dev-site-error_log"
     CustomLog "/Users/you/log/apache2/dev-site-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thats really helpful, but I'm still not getting anything when I go to my specified port. I've got my path set up currectly, but what do I input for server name, and how do I start that server?

Comment: Make sure that you add an entry in your /etc/hosts file that points dev.site.com to your localhost. Then you will be able to go to dev.site.com in your browser. You may need to make sure that Apache is running first. I forget how to do that in your Mac Settings but I think you can also run the command "apachectl start"